# How can I understand this combinatorics identity on an example?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I understand this identity on an example?

$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2{n \choose k} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$

For the left side it could be like I am choosing k people from n for each k > 0 and then 2 people from the k chosen people with chosing the same person twice allowed and order matters, only when k = 1 order does not matter. How can I say it similarly with the right side?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binomial summation $\sum\binom nkk^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735383/binomial-summation-sum-binom-nkk2) (See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2920663/546503 for a combinatorial proof)

Comment: But does it not count examples where you choose from k 2-times the same person twice?

Comment: If your point is potential duplication, no there is none, at least in the answer by Batominovski. If you can elaborate your point, I can explain or you could leave a comment against the answer and if the member is active, they could respond to you.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.